Does pinescript that allow you to hide numerical values on the Y-axis
I'm preparing an indicator whose output is relative. The actual values are not only meaningless, but distracting. Is there some pinescript code that will prevent these values from being displayed on the Y-axis?
To further clarify, I'm not trying to remove the highlights on the  Y-axis that mark the current value of the indicator (e.g. as would be done with:

display = - display.price_scale

I'm trying to suppress the display of all values on the Y-axis as illustrated in this image. 
Also note that

scale=scale.none

in the indicator call statement is not a solution because this won't compile unless the indicator is an overlay.

Why display values you don't want on the chart in the first place? Instead of adding extra code, try removing the drawing or plotting functions from the source code so they won't appear on the chart. This way, you can still use the indicator's logic for further calculations.

I want the line on the chart ti display. I just don't want the to appear on the Y-axis. The numbers themselves are irrelevant, but the relative changes in the indicator are critical.

You can use display.all - display.price_scale.
Below code will display high and low prices. The high (green) price will be displayed everywhere, whereas the low (red) price will be displayed everwhere except the price scale.
//@version=6
indicator("My script")

plot(high, "High", color.green, display=display.all)
plot(low, "Low", color.red, display=display.all - display.price_scale)



Thanks, but that wasn't quite what I was looking for. See the updates to my question for more information.
